# Create New file using File Dialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I create a new file using file dialog with pyqt5?
This is my code so far, it prints out the correct path after I create the new file but it doesn't actually create it

```
def newFile(self):
    name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()
    print(name)
```

Comment: It doesn't, and it shouldn't. It's up to you to create it. How to do it depends on what you want to store in that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName) function does not create or save a file as indicated in the docs:

> This is a convenience static function that will **return a file name selected by the user**. The file does not have to exist.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Actually a dialog is created that allows the user to establish the name of a file that the developer must take as a reference to save the information they want, so what you should do is verify the filename is not empty and use it to create the file:

```py
filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()
if filename:
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        # write contents
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def newFile(self):
    name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File')
    file = open(name,'w')
    text = ""
    file.write(text)
    file.close()
```